# How to model a Many-to-many relation when the target model is a tuple in django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model with translated text fields. Now the issue is that often i don't have translations for 'some' languages and i do like to publish the models already.

An easy (default) ay out is to fallback to the default language (as per django model translations) but actually i'm thinking of explicitly enabling the instance for a language. For this i like to have a many-to-many relation with the LANGUAGES tuple from settings. So basically it's like a CharField with choices set to LANGUAGES but then in a select many fashion.

One idea is to add a Language model for this and create a standard ManyToMany relation; but it doesn't feel right since i have nothing to add except for the language code itself; so why add a model....

Another alternative is to apply a PickleField and serialize a [] of language-codes. But that obviously is a quick/dirty solution as there is no validation etc...

Anyone an idea on this issue?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres, you could use an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield), which maps to the db's built-in array support, to store a list of the selected language codes.

If not, it's relatively simple to write a custom field that stores a comma-separated list of codes and translates it to/from a list - there are probably third-party implementations out there already.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list of language codes into string by using JSON and store it as string. For this, you can add model methods in your model.

```
import json

class Product(models.Model):
    languages = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def set_languages(self, list_of_language_codes):
        self.languages = json.dumps(list_of_language_codes)

    @property
    def get_languages(self):
        return json.loads(self.languages)
```

Then, after saving the object, invoke set_languages() method with list of language codes -

```
object.set_languages(list_if_language_codes)    
object.save()
```

Comment: This does not give me control over the selected languages via the admin interface. Also i like to be able to query for enabled instances given the current language.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I found a solution that is both extremely simple, and can be controlled in admin views + i can even query if the instance is enabled for a specific language.

The solution is provided by model-translations itself (django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/…), if you simply create a boolean field enabled and register than field to be translated, you get an enabled_ field for each.... !

```
class <model>TranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name', 'slug', 'enabled', ...)

translator.register(...
```